# How to use JPA or Hibernate @JoinTable with extra join conditions like SQL => from a join b on a.no = b.no or b.no is null

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I want to use JPA or Hibernate join , the SQL output like :

```
    select
        *
    from
        a 
    inner join
        b 
            on a.no=b.MAIN_NO 
            and (a.SN=b.SN or b.SN is null)
            and (a.SN_SUB=b.SN_SUB or b.SN_SUB is null)
```

but now my output :

```
   select
        *
    from
        a 
    inner join
        b 
            on a.no=b.MAIN_NO 
            and a.SN=b.SN
            and a.SN_SUB=b.SN_SUB
```

my code like:

```
Entity
@Table(name = "contract")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column
    private String no;

    @Id
    @Column
    private String sn;

    @Id
    @Column
    private String snSub;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "Relation1,
               joinColumns = {
               @JoinColumn(name = "MAIN_NO" ,referencedColumnName="NO"),
               @JoinColumn(name = "SN" ,referencedColumnName="SN"),
               @JoinColumn(name = "SN_SUB" ,referencedColumnName="SN_SUB"),
               },
               inverseJoinColumns = {
               @JoinColumn(name = "company_code" ,referencedColumnName="company_code"),
               @JoinColumn(name = "lessor_no" ,referencedColumnName="lessor_no"),
               }
    )
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private List<Relation2> relations;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

Table Relation1 is a SQL VIEW table
but Relation2 is not

In the contract table sn not null and in the Relation1 table sn maybe have null but I still must to join

How to use JPA or Hibernate to meets the need ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The "extra join conditions" you describe are not related to the join.

They are syntactic shorthand describing the where clause.
Join the table based on matching foreign and private key only.

Put the conditions in the where clause, where they belong.

Comment: If you want to join where one table has a null value, that is an example of an outer join rather than inner join.